# Chrome specific Javascript scope issue

Tags: javascript, asp.net, google-chrome

I have a javascript function being defined in the head of an ASPX page:

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
    function bdScheduler() {
                var CanRun = '<%= ScheduleCheck() %>';
                if ('Success' == CanRun) {
                    bcal = window.open('ProjSchedBckwdCalc.aspx?po_rec=<%= lblpodate_R.Text %>', '', 'width=650px, height=750px');
                } else {
                    alert(CanRun);
                }
            }
</script>
```

`ScheduleCheck()` is a function defined in my code behind, that is working as intended to check dependancies and return a string dictating whether the page 'ProjSchedBckwdCalc.aspx' can do it's job or not.  If 'Success', then we popup a window at the desired location passing it a value from a label on the current page.  Otherwise, we alert the message we get back from `ScheduleCheck()`.

I'm calling this from the onclick event of a regular anchor tag:

```
<a href="#" onclick="bdScheduler();" >Backward Scheduler</a>
```

Code posted works for me in the current and a few previous builds of Firefox, Chrome, and IE, however I'm getting users reporting in that the button does nothing.  I checked it out a bit and they're all using Chrome (same version as one on my test machine), and the console shows that the browser doesn't see `bdScheduler()`.

My question is in 2 parts:  Why is it that certain Chrome installations are handling this differently in identical builds, and what can I change to get it to not only behave consistently, but run the desired function and check when it does?

EDIT: Rendered code:

```
    function bdScheduler() {
                var CanRun = 'Success';
                if ('Success' == CanRun) {
                    bcal = window.open('ProjSchedBckwdCalc.aspx?po_rec=12/23/2013', '', 'width=650px, height=750px');
                } else {
                    alert(CanRun);
                }
            }
```

Comment: Are they getting any errors? Is it possible that the text from `ScheduleCheck()` or `lblpodate_R.Text` has a single quote in it which terminates your strings and breaks your code? Have you looked at the actual rendered markup to see what the code looks like?

Comment: Is the button is inside a form?

Comment: @cannon: edited in rendered code

Comment: @EricHerlitz yes, the link resides in a form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing wrong your your code (http://jsfiddle.net/N3Unt/6/), I've tested in Chrome on three different Macs and on Windows 7 & 8 and also FF / IE where available.

What you always must do is to ensure that all code is loaded and that nothing is cached. A proper and more modern way to do "onclicks" is to use a decoupling pattern called eventhandling

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    var link = document.getElementById('yourOnClickLink');

    // onClick's logic:
    link.addEventListener('click', function() {
        var CanRun = '<%= ScheduleCheck() %>';
        if ('Success' == CanRun) {
            // Warning, bcal becomes global using this code (ANTIPATTERN)
            bcal = window.open('ProjSchedBckwdCalc.aspx?po_rec=12/23/2013', '', 'width=650px, height=750px');
        } else {
            alert(CanRun);
        }        
    });
});
```

This ensures everything is loaded properly and your page can load asynchronously. Why not grey out any link that is connected to the eventhandler and enable it when the DOM is loaded, ah great fun :)

Comment: Thank you for the verification and pointing me in the right direction.  Turns out the sql admin didn't grant execute for our users on an sp that the vb function runs.